# Task manager like windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where’s the “task manager”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2123/wheres-the-task-manager)

Is there a way to make it similar, I like knowing what is going on with my hard drive and system resources.

Comment: What's wrong with System Monitor, I haven't seen Win 8 version of Task manager, but system monitor is pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gnome-system-monitor.
Or in an Terminal "top" (q to exit).