# Task manager a UI like with Windows 10's one

Tags: indicator, disk-usage, process, network-monitoring

I like the UI in the Windows 10 task manager:

[image]

In particular, I like the fact that the most important four shared resources on a computer are displayed without spurious information, and the color-coding that lets me figure out immediately the major offenders.

I have seen several process monitors and task managers in Linux, but nothing that matches the clarity of this display. In particular, most task managers limit themselves to CPU and memory.

**Is there a process manager for Linux that mimics this GUI?**

EDIT to make the question clearer: I am looking for a task manager that clearly displays the information in those four columns: a breakup of processor, memory, disk and network usage by process, possibly in an uncluttered UI and without other spurious information. I can find plenty of system monitoring tools on Linux that display only the first two columns of that table. I can also find tools that plot total network usage vs. time. Both do not seem as effective as Windows 10's task manager: they do not allow me to immediately identify which of the four is the bottleneck on my system and which process uses up the most of that resource.

Comment: (I think that this is *not* a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/225804/task-manager-like-windows-8 -- it's a more precise question asking for a specific feature.)

Answer (score 9):

I use [system monitor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/quantal/gnome-system-monitor/). But, I guess [Stacer](https://github.com/oguzhaninan/Stacer) will meet your choice better

Stacer will show you the culprit using system resources better. As you can see in the screen shot 3, Stacer can list an ascending or descending listing based on CPU or Memory memory consumption. You can see which process is using CPU the most, which process is using Memory the most, likewise. Only colour coding is missing from what you seek. Stacer also gives total CPU and Memory usage.

You can get all these with System Monitor as well.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can find more options here

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/11/5-system-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu

Comment: *Only colour coding is missing from what you seek*: No: the columns with disk and network I/O are missing, too. Most resource monitors that list CPU and memory usage (starting from `top`); it's disk and network I/O that are difficult to find.

Answer (score 6):

I had also the same Problem, KSysGaurd is great but requires plugins to install and is similar to gnome-system-monitor. KSysGaurd has advance options but not very simple. Personally, I didn't like either the KSysGaurd and Gnome-system-monitor.

Check out my approach for the same: https://github.com/KrispyCamel4u/SysMonTask.

Some highlights are:
[image: CPU Performance Tab]

**Update**: Now I have added the user Processes in version 1.1.0

I have filtered out the background Processes(with some exception)  and shown only user-specific Processes (user parent and child process like in windows) which makes it easy to spot processes that you are interested in instead of finding out from the pool of all process that gnome-system-monitor shows.

**Also it includes the aggregates(on the column header) of all the processes.**

[image: Process Tab]

There are only a few processes that are kinds of background but still appear: The exceptions :(

**Update**: Now I have added the logical CPU utilization in version 1.1.1-beta
[image: logical processor]

Suggestions are most welcomed in improving.

Thanks

Comment: This looks so good I want to have this one in py Kubuntu :)

Comment: The process tab in KDE will not be shown properly but the performance will work as it should. Wait for some time for a new release for process tab compatibility.

Comment: @Irsu85 sysmontask now supports all distros, I hope it would help you.

Comment: This is great. The process tab in GNOME Fedora does not allow sorting by column headers, but its awesome in every other way.

Answer (score 5):

How about [Glances](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Glances)?

[image: glances screenshot]

See [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/293447/507051) for details and other answers there for just a quick overview of choices.

Comment: Thanks! This is a better match than the previous answers; it has disk a I/O column in addition to CPu and MEM. Still missing "network" though, so I'll leave time for other answers.

Comment: Did you play around with it and try pressing <kbd>n</kbd>? This should `Show/hide network stats`…

Comment: I tried it and no, it does not add a column with per-process network traffic  --- it only hides the "network" pane that you can see in the leftmost column of the screenshot.

Comment: You're right, that's missing, let's give it some time, maybe somebody knows a better match. However if not, you're free to submit a feature request on [glaces' github page](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances/issues) – that's the open source way, and that's the way all software should be developed and improved. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling with the same question and I did not find something with similar good overview (esp that also includes disk I/O, network, CPU/RAM) so I started my own project, "LikeTaskManager" with exactly that goal to mimic the function.

Have a look at:
https://github.com/rejuce/LikeTaskManager

[image: Screenshot of cpu tab]

now Version 2 with process list tab
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I like this!

Comment: The github page says: *"Should work on all Linux flavours newer than Ubut 16.04"* (SIC) but I'm still using Ubuntu 16.04 and will have to wait until later this year or next before trying this out.

Comment: sorry, equal or newer!

Comment: now some polishing is done and v2 released. I added also the process list tab, which shows cpu, ram, disk I/O AND network I/O per process (network I/O requires root though)

Comment: That new **Processes** tab released today is awesome. Now if only someone can figure out how **Firefox** can report it's usage by opened tab instead of the whole app.

Answer (score 3):

As a more recent answer in late 2021, there is an another task manager on Linux, System Monitoring Center. Here is the [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/system-monitoring-center/) for the application page.

It has very advanced features like managing applications on startup and managing services. Also sensor information is available under performance tab.
Currently beta versions are available on the page.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is [KSysGuard from KDE](https://userbase.kde.org/KSysGuard). The UI is pretty much similar to Windows. Helped me a lot when I was migrating from windows to Ubuntu.

[KSysGuard in Kubuntu 17.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnc80.png)

Comment: This one has no disk and network I/O columns, either, it seems. Please check the final part of mu question.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use `htop`, and I think that while it doesn't look very similar to the Windows 10 Task Manager, it shows a lot of the same information, and more:

[image: htop screenshot]

You can install it by running `sudo apt install htop`